# cadena de conexion Web.config // utilizando ConfigurationManager

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, web.config

Estoy realizando la conexion de Sql Server por medio de Web.config con ConfigurationManager pero no contecta ni genera error ya agregue referencias.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="cnn"  connectionString="server=DESKTOPOCJDGUN\\SQLEXPRESS01;database=COMPAGO;Integrated Security=true"  providerName= "System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings> 

List<Cliente> lista = null;
string cadena = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnn"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cadena))
```

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: ¿te puedes  conectar sin usuario y contraseña? Salvo que despues de using  estés abriendo  la conexión con usuario y contraseña